# How to apply an attribute, say 'disabled' to a button which is present in a different region?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have attached an image here to explain my issue better. Please check the image as well.

[image]

The image shows a drop down with several options. The 'Create Users' button is disabled by default in the html file. I want the 'Create Users' button to be enabled when I select 'City' from the drop down. Please note that the lower panel i.e. the buttons 'Create Users' and 'Cancel' are in a regions different from the region where the mapping is taking place.

My code so far is :

```
if(this.model.attributes.systemColumnName === 'City')
        {

            this.$('#createButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
```

This code isn't working for me.

I would be pleased to see replies on how I could solve this issue.

Comment: You can trigger an event through eventaggregator and listen it in the view which contains the 'Create Users' button

Comment: Thank u. But I am looking for a code to track how i could assign the required property to the buttons in the appropriate region.

Comment: in that case can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) then it will be better to help you

Comment: I wish I could, but the code is apparently written in 2 html files and 2 js files. Hence, I am finding it real difficult to create a fiddle. Could there be any other way that I could get some help please?

Comment: can you post the files here

Comment: If your button is in another region obviously it will be in another view. Am I right?

Comment: nope @nikhilmehta. Its the same view that I am rendering.

Comment: Can you show the model and view structure? It's quite difficult to know why it's not working without to provide a minimal code. Where you are checking condition? On click event? What it's not working? Error messages you receive?

Comment: well these are the regions that I have used inside a js file.regions:{
            'tableBodyRegion':'#columnMatchTable',
            'responseRegion':'#loaderPageHolder'
        },

Comment: This does not help at all.

Comment: Here goes the code:

var BodyView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile(TemplateString),
        regions:{
            'tableBodyRegion':'#columnMatchTable',
            'responseRegion':'#loaderPageHolder'
        },

var reg = this.tableBodyRegion.show(new mappingTableRow.CView({
              options : options,
              collection : _this.getOption('respCollection')
            }));

This was from the first js file

Comment: hey all! i was able to finally do this. The method that i used was passing the region as a parameter to the function that was being invoked on the button click.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if it doesn't work.
Hope this helps:

```
if(this.model.attributes.systemColumnName === 'City') {
    this.$('#createButton').prop('disabled', false);
}
```